# How to get selected value of a <select> element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Given the following HTML and JavaScript, what do I need to change to get the selected value?

```html
<select id="col_1" name="col_1" class="columnMapping">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Ignore</option>
  <option value="2">Location</option>
  <option value="3">Department</option>
  <option value="4">Role</option>
  <option value="5" selected="selected">User Name</option>
  <option value="6">First Name</option>
  <option value="7">Last Name</option>
  <option value="8">Email</option>
  <option value="9">Status</option>
  <option value="10">AltId</option>
  <option value="11">Phone Number</option>
  <option value="12">Reports To User Name</option>
  <option value="13">Reports To AltId</option>
</select>
<!-- More similar <select> elements to follow... -->
```

```js
var arrSelectedVals = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $('table.dataTable select.columnMapping').length; i++) {
  arrSelectedVals.push($('table.dataTable select.columnMapping').eq(i).find(':selected').val());
}
```

I keep getting an array of empty strings.

Comment: `$('.columnMapping').val()`

Comment: `$('table.dataTable select.columnMapping').val()`. No loop needed

Answer (score -2):

What if you tried something like this (assuming no jQuery or whatever)?

```
<select id="col_1" name="col_1" class="columnMapping" onchange="onChange()">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Ignore</option>
  <option value="2">Location</option>
  <option value="3">Department</option>
  <option value="4">Role</option>
...
```

Then later:

```
function onChange() {
    value = document.querySelector('#col_1').value;
    console.log(value);  // should be the value of whatever was selected
}
```